# How to Output a Set as Simple Strings?

Tags: clojure

I need to give an output like this:

```
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-41.jpg
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-42.jpg
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-43.jpg
/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-10.jpg
/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-11.jpg
/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-19.jpg
```

But I think my output is a set:

```
#{"/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-10.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-43.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-42.jpg" "/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-19.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-41.jpg" "/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-11.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc"}
```

Any ideas how can I convert that set into this output?

Comment: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join

Comment: @cfrick It is still a failure, but now I think it fails because of the order of the list items. I tried "sort" to order them but it does not work. Any advice on how to put them in the above order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sort`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort) with [`clojure.string/join`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join):

```
(->> #{"/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-10.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-43.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-42.jpg" "/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-19.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-41.jpg" "/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-11.jpg" "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc"}
     sort
     (clojure.string/join "\n")
     println)
```

Output:

```
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-41.jpg
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-42.jpg
/Fotos/Azoren-2018/restaurant/dc-43.jpg
/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-10.jpg
/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-11.jpg
/Fotos/Mallorca-2017/dc-19.jpg
=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did this and now it says 0 failures, 0 errors!!:                                    (clojure.string/join "\n" (sort (disj (clojure.set/difference (load-string-set (no-prefix prefix-davor) davor)
                        (load-string-set (no-prefix prefix-danach) danach)) "/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet/dc-40.jpg"
"/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet/dc-41.jpg"
"/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet/dc-42.jpg"
"/Fotos/Azoren-2018/buffet/dc-43.jpg"))))